# Challenge: create a list by sorting a bunch of nested dict

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to set a `sort()` function to work with a complex data structure.

Here's the data:

```
{
    "GROUP-A": {
        "key-A1": {
            "GROUP-B": {
                "key-B1": {
                    "GROUP-C": {
                        "key-C1": 100,
                        "key-C2": 850,
                        "key-C3": 50
                    }
                },
                "key-B2": {
                    "GROUP-C": {
                        "key-C1": 700,
                        "key-C2": 1100,
                        "key-C3": 500
                    }
                },
                "key-B3": {
                    "GROUP-C": {
                        "key-C1": 150,
                        "key-C2": 300,
                        "key-C3": 450
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "key-A2": {
            "GROUP-B": {
                "key-B1": {
                    "GROUP-C": {
                        "key-C1": 0,
                        "key-C2": 0,
                        "key-C3": 0
                    }
                },
                "key-B2": {
                    "GROUP-C": {
                        "key-C1": 50,
                        "key-C2": 150,
                        "key-C3": 250
                    }
                },
                "key-B3": {
                    "GROUP-C": {
                        "key-C1": 150,
                        "key-C2": 50,
                        "key-C3": 200
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "key-A3": {
            "GROUP-B": {
                "key-B1": {
                    "GROUP-C": {
                        "key-C1": 100000,
                        "key-C2": 0,
                        "key-C3": 0
                    }
                },
                "key-B2": {
                    "GROUP-C": {
                        "key-C1": 0,
                        "key-C2": 0,
                        "key-C3": 0
                    }
                },
                "key-B3": {
                    "GROUP-C": {
                        "key-C1": 0,
                        "key-C2": 0,
                        "key-C3": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also consider that I have multiple `key-Ax` dictionaries.

What I'm trying to return is the list of dict of type `key-A` ordered by the values in `key-C` but without changing the data structure inside that key.

For example, with the data supplied above, I would expect to see:

```
[{"key-A3":{..}},{"key-A1":{..}},{"key-A2":{..}}]
```

Is this something achievable with a single `sort()` function or it is just too complicated?

Probably something of this type:

```
filtered = sorted(data["GROUP-A"].items(), key= lambda kv: (??????))
```

I've been tinkering with the lambda function for a while, but I couldn't get anything to work as expected.

If it can be done, can you please explain the steps involved? I would die to understand how you break the problem in smaller parts... and the reasoning behind it.

Thanks!

Edit: here's a link to an online python editor if you want to give it a try http://repl.it/MDY/1

Comment: You object doesn't work when I put it in python. Errors in `"key-B3"`.

Comment: @Hoopdady Sorry, you are right: I wrote it by hand and there was a typo. I fixed it and tested on jsonlint. It's now a valid dictionary.

Comment: What have you tried? What result did you get? How is that different from the result you expected?

Comment: I don't understand your criterion, why should key-A3 end up before key-A1?

Comment: @misha basically I tried a number of 'lambda' functions, but that is my weakness: it's easy when your data structure stops at one level. I don't understand how to traverse the dictionary to check the values in `key-C`.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich because one of the values at `key-C` level in `key-A3` is higher than all the others in `key-A1`.

Comment: OK, so what matters is the maximum of the key-C values under each key-A3.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Yep! exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain together multiple list comprehensions to iterate through the various layers of your dictionary.

```
filtered = sorted(data["GROUP-A"].items(), key= lambda kv: max(value for group_b in kv[1].itervalues() for key_b in group_b.itervalues() for group_c in key_b.itervalues() for value in group_c.itervalues()))
print filtered
```

Result:

```
[
    ('key-A2', {...}), 
    ('key-A1', {...}), 
    ('key-A3', {...})
]
```

(Use the keyword argument `reverse=True` if you want the items ordered largest to smallest)

It may be better to make a more readable helper function, at the expense of a few lines.

```
def get_biggest_c_value(key_a):
    values = []
    for group_b in key_a.itervalues():
        for key_b in group_b.itervalues():
            for group_c in key_b.itervalues():
                for value in group_c.itervalues():
                    values.append(value)
    return max(values)

filtered = sorted(data["GROUP-A"].items(), key=lambda kv: get_biggest_c_value(kv[1]))
print filtered
```

Comment: Hey @Kevin, Thank you! Is there any known performance benefit by using lambda functions vs an helper?

Comment: Hard to say. The best thing to do is profile the performance of both, using an amount of data you're likely to handle in your actual application, and judge which is better for you. I suspect it would only make an imperceptible difference, however.